# Telegram-cli argument --phone/-u not work

Tags: linux, bash, arguments, telegram

I use the development of telegram-cli.
I need at the first authorization to skip the question of "phone number"

The argument does not help me, or I do not use it that way.

```
telegram-cli -k /etc/telegram-cli/tg-server.pub --phone +71110001100
```

What am I doing wrong?

https://github.com/vysheng/tg/wiki/Telegram-CLI-Arguments

without "plus" same problem

```
evgen@ovz3:~$ telegram-cli --phone 71110001100 -k /etc/telegram-cli/tg-server.pub
Telegram-cli version 1.4.1, Copyright (C) 2013-2015 Vitaly Valtman
Telegram-cli comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `show_license'.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `show_license' for details.
Telegram-cli uses libtgl version 2.1.0
Telegram-cli includes software developed by the OpenSSL Project
for use in the OpenSSL Toolkit. (http://www.openssl.org/)
I: config dir=[/home/evgen/.telegram-cli]
phone number:
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I solved my problem with https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto

Answer (score 0):

To start with telegram-cli, I did the following actions on debian :

1. as a normal user, run `telegram-cli`
2. the prompt waits for a phone number, the main form is '+xx x xx xx xx xx', at least for france.

=> then you get a code on your phone, type it at the telegram-cli prompt

At this step I can view telegram conversations I have from my phone, but I don't know yet how to send a telegram message manually from telegram-cli.